# Why is the raw file path not working in python?

Tags: python

I have looked and tried different methods posted online but I cant get this to work.

This is my file path:

```
file_path = '\\something.com\1400_somethingelse\1400_somethingyes\1400_Design\1500_sketch\ShotCam'
```

This file path is going to change multiple times so I need this to become a variable.

I have tried  using the following in order to convert it into a raw file as another variable:

- the **r** before to get the raw file path and that works but what happens if this file path is going to be change? Naturally I would need a variable
- I have used the **repr(file_path)** and that works in some cases but when I try to use the **os.listdir** it doesnt!
- I have tried the **r'%s' %file_path** as well but nothing

Im sure its something very simple so please let me know if someone has an answer for this!

Thank you!

**UPDATE
This is the code Im having problems with:

```
variable = '\\something.com\1400_somethingelse\1400_somethingyes\1400_Design\1500_sketch\ShotCam'
#Result:\something.com`0_somethingelse`0_somethingyes`0_Designh0_sketch\ShotCam

raw_path= repr(variable)
#Result:'\\something.com\x0somethingelse\x0somethingyes\x0Designh\x00_sketch\\ShotCam'

list_dir = os.listdir(raw_path)
print list_dir
#Result: # Error: WindowsError: file <maya console> line 8: 3 #
```

To make it a raw path I know I have to do:

```
variable = r'\\something.com\1400_somethingelse\1400_somethingyes\1400_Design\1500_sketch\ShotCam'
```

But I want this to become a variable so I can change it multiple times.

Comment: That's not a raw string. `r'\\something\1400_somethingelse\...'` is.

Comment: What's the problem here, though? What does "cant get this to work" mean, exactly?

Comment: Raw strings are *purely* a syntactic convenience for defining a `str` value. The objects created by `'\\foo'` and `r'\foo'` are *identical*.

Comment: Most Python functions can translate a path internally as necessary. `os.listdir('//something.com/1400_something/...')` should work across multiple platforms.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I have updated the post in order to be more clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Jose7: Still not clear. It's already a variable. The raw string syntax makes it work. If it's not a string literal, the backslashes you read from another source will be literal backslashes (`\ ` being an escape character is specific to string literals; reading from a file won't turn them into escapes). Are you looking for `os.path.join` or something?

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger, thank you for your reply! Yes actually, my previous answer that I posted didnt solve my problem but thank you for clarifying the terms(post deleted). I think Im doing this too fast. In the updated post I mentioned that this variable is going to change many times so I need this path to be in a variable. So naturally, I cant just add the `r` in front, I would need to do this later. That is why I used the ` `raw_path` variable. In here, I dont know what is the best way to get a result where I can use the `os.listdir` to access the files inside

Comment: @Jose7: *How*  are you changing it many times? If string literals are involved, use raw strings for every change. When no literals are involved, it should already work, because backslashes aren't special for strings not produced from literals.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I have a window where you can type your own path. So this is where it changes many times. If I just use the typed string then I get this error : `# Error: WindowsError: file <maya console> line 9: 3 #`.

Comment: @Jose7: You need to provide a [MCVE] of the code that does this. Odds are it's flawed in some way, but we can't fix it without assistance.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I only have the 4 lines of code that I wrote in the post where I have the issue. I have updated the post and I have typed the results for each line, I hope that helps and thank you again for helping me!

Comment: @Jose7: That does not include *anything* related to "I have a window where you can type your own path". That's what we need to see.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I dont see why would you need it. This is an isolated problem Im having. I have removed this lines of code to a new file in order to understand how to handle the paths. I only need to get access to the file list in the written file path

Comment: @Jose7: Your claim is that the dynamic variable is a problem. Your existing code works fine with raw strings. You claim that doesn't work for you. We can't provide assistance with code we can't see. You can't magically change a busted string into a working one. `os.listdir` has nothing to do with this. You need a `str` that has the correct backslashes, not interpreted as string escapes, doesn't matter how its being used.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes that is what Im trying to get, the correct backslashes. Files are within a network so I want the user to simply copy and paste the folder path and get access to the files in order to do an action that Im working on. I dont know how to replicate the issue so you can test it since it is within our network. I will try to dig more on the issue and post any updates. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

- You can verify that your string is not a valid path by just printing it.

```
>>> '\\something.com\1400_somethingelse\1400_somethingyes\1400_Design\1500_sketch\ShotCam'
'\\something.com`0_somethingelse`0_somethingyes`0_Designh0_sketch\\ShotCam'
>>> r'\\something.com\1400_somethingelse\1400_somethingyes\1400_Design\1500_sketch\ShotCam'
'\\\\something.com\\1400_somethingelse\\1400_somethingyes\\1400_Design\\1500_sketch\\ShotCam'
```

- use `r` to escape those `\`.

Comment: thank you @Poojan ! I have updated my post so its more clear what I want to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: @Jose7 using `r''` in your variable is not working? `variable = r'\\something.com\...'`

Comment: hi @Poojan, it works perfectly. But like I mentioned in the updated post is that this file path is going to change many times so the path itself needs to be a variable and I need to turn it into raw in another variable or in another way in order to access the `os.listdir` files